# DynamoDB for PHP sessions

Tags: php, session, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

we are currently using a NAS for PHP session files storage for an array of autoscaling load balanced app servers.

We are interested to replace this with a more robust solution and DynamoDB from Amazon looks interesting. I see one possible issue here, documented here:

http://thwartedefforts.org/2006/11/11/race-conditions-with-ajax-and-php-sessions/

I suspect DynamoDB does not support object locking. Any workarounds you can think of?

If you have any experience from other NoSQL systems used for PHP sessions also feel free to jump in as the learnings might be similar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using DynamoDB's conditional writes, you could implement a pessimistic locking scheme similar to the way PHP's default session handler works.

Someone else has also made a request for a DynamoDB session handler: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=328060.

**Updated:** The AWS SDK for PHP now includes a session handler for DynamoDB. See https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/blob/master/extensions/dynamodbsessionhandler.class.php and http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#i=DynamoDBSessionHandler

**Updated:** There is an article about the DynamoDB session handler on the AWS blog: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/04/scalable-session-handling-in-php-using-amazon-dynamodb.html

Comment: +1 for implementing this and letting us know immediately, thanks much!

Comment: Ah damn. I spent the week before writing my own and was going to share it. :( Thanks for the update though!

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea (+1) - and an elaborate article indeed, just skimmed it for now though ;)

Regarding other NoSQL options for PHP session storage you might want to check out [MongoSession – A PHP MongoDB Session Handler](http://www.jqueryin.com/projects/mongo-session/), which references [Race Conditions with Ajax and PHP Sessions](http://thwartedefforts.org/2006/11/11/race-conditions-with-ajax-and-php-sessions/) as well and seems to address the documented issues in the meantime:

> I have recently updated the library to support [atomic operations](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) on
>   both session writes and garbage collection to help prevent these race
>   conditions.

A similar approach should be possible with [Amazon DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) as well by means of an appropriate combination of *Conditional Updates*, *Atomic Counters* and *Consistent Reads*, see [Working with Items in Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithDDItems.html) for details on those concepts and/or check out the following FAQ entries:

- [Does Amazon DynamoDB support conditional operations?](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#Does_Amazon_DynamoDB_support_conditional_operations) - *Yes, you can specify a condition that must be satisfied for a PUT, update, or delete operation on an item to be completed. [...] Conditional operations allow users to implement optimistic concurrency control systems on DynamoDB.*
- [Does Amazon DynamoDB support increment or decrement operations?](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/#Does_Amazon_DynamoDB_support_increment_or_decrement_operations) - *Yes, Amazon DynamoDB allows atomic increment and decrement operations on scalar values.*

Comment: Thanks for the rapid and detailed answer! Consistent Reads would go a long way to help indeed. Atomic increment and decrement operations would help but it is not always increment and decrement changes that need to be applied in an atomic fashion. As such the lack of locks might still be an issue. thanks for pointing in the right direction! I ll investigate further!

Answer (score 1):

Your servers are on AWS? Why don't you try the ElastCache feature? http://aws.amazon.com/en/elasticache/

I use CakePHP, witch supports DB and Memcache to store sessions. After some some time studding both, I've opted for Memcache. Actually, I set PHP to store sessions on Memcache and set CakePHP to use php sessions config. This way I can separate my memcache instances for sessions and caching.

Regards.

Comment: That's an option we are considering as well and is extremely easy to setup. Only issue there is that when a node dies or when the cache gets full, sessions will be lost. Since nodes do not die often and cache getting full can be solved with careful capacity planning it can be a workable solution indeed.

Comment: @webgr Loosing clients session is really annoying, but it's usually accepted. On one of my applications it is very dangerous, but I'm taking the risk. I can have problems on my DB, too. It's the same kind of risk. Amazon claims that EC is really reliable and has failover, but I do think you can loose data on a failure. "Reliable – Amazon ElastiCache has multiple features that enhance reliability for critical production deployments, including automatic failure detection and recovery. Amazon ElastiCache runs on the same highly reliable infrastructure used by other Amazon Web Services."

Answer (score 1):

Amazon just release the new DynamoDB Session feature: http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/04/scalable-session-handling-in-php-using-amazon-dynamodb.html